# Java Swing application Message dialog help

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am working on a Java Swing application. I need to create a dialog like that shown in the figure. I do not know the name for this; I can not explain, so I am attaching a picture.
Please tell what this is called and how I can create it in my GUI application.

[image: Image is like this]

Comment: looks like as Custom ToolTip, BaloonTip based on un-decoreted JDialog#Modality

Comment: Please explain what you want: a yellow box? deleted items? highlighted text? custom close decoration?

Comment: It appears to be some sort of status or message bar.  I don't recall if there's a built in way to do this in Swing (my experience is very limited) but perhaps this will help you find it.

Comment: @ trashgod i Need a yellow box, and a Cross Button to close this dialog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*There's more than one way to skin a cat*.

---

```
public final class JDialogDemo {
    private static BufferedImage bi;
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            loadImage();
            
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    createAndShowGUI();
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    private static void loadImage() throws IOException{
        bi = ImageIO.read(JDialogDemo.class.getResource("../resource/close-icon.png"));
    }
    
    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setUndecorated(true);
        
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
                return new Dimension(400, 40);
            }
        };
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY));
        panel.setBackground(new Color(238, 221, 130));
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        
        final JLabel closeLabel = new JLabel();
        closeLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi));
        closeLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                dialog.dispose();
            }
        });
        
        panel.add(new JLabel("There are deleted items that used to be in this folder."));
        panel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        panel.add(closeLabel);
        dialog.add(panel);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

---

This is simply a demonstration. Feel free to tailor this however you like.

Comment: +1 See also this [variation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762984/java-swing-application-message-dialog-help/6766983#6766983).

Answer (score 5):

Another handy source for icons is the `UIManager`. In this case, the `JInternalFrame` Look & Feel `closeIcon` has some appeal, but [others](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) are also available.

Modifying @Moonbeam's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762984/java-swing-application-message-dialog-help/6763960#6763960) produces the result below.

```
private static final Icon icon = UIManager.getIcon("InternalFrame.closeIcon");
...
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    ...
    closeLabel.setIcon(icon);
    ...
}
```

[image: JDialogDemo]

Comment: I am intrigued that this `closeIcon` actually closes the dialog!

Comment: +1, Very nice. Regarding your comment, meaning you didn't need to add a `MouseListener`?

Comment: @Moonbeam: D'oh, I overlooked the `MouseListener`! BTW, you may need to set the composite in `GradientPaintDemo`, as suggested [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/composite). Also, don't `dispose()` a graphics context you didn't create.

Comment: I appreciate the link and advice. But I certainly do dispose of a graphics context that I created. It's a copy. :)

Comment: @Moonbeam: D'oh, again. I was distracted by Dr. Evil? :-)