# JInternalFrame adding an icon to the title bar

Tags: java, swing, icons, jinternalframe

I'd like to add an `ImageIcon` or comparable to a `JInternalFrame`'s titlebar such that the [x] icon is east-most, the iconable icon is second east-most, and a custom icon is third east-most. Is this doable?

Comment: There is no easy way to do this. This is the responsibility of the LAF.

Comment: @camickr is correct, but the icons are [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762984/java-swing-application-message-dialog-help/6766983#6766983) if you want to use them in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("Iconos/icono.png"));
this.setFrameIcon(icon);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
JInternalFrame jInternalFrame1 = new JInternalFrame("Test Internal Frame",false,false,false,false);

try {
  URL url = new URL("images/icon.gif");
  ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
  jInternalFrame1.setFrameIcon(icon);
} 
catch (MalformedURLException ex) 
{
   //whatever you want to put here
}
```

Comment: this will change the default top-left icon, not add an additional one? Ya?

Answer (score -1):

for obtain for parent frame :
    // parent is container jDesktopPane ->  parent = new JFrame ()

```
this.setFrameIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(this.parent.getIconImage()));
```